# Querying DocumentDb in .NET with a parametrized query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

For an application I'm running a query on DocumentDb in .NET. For this used I wanted to use a parametrized query, like this:

```
var sqlString = "select p.Id, p.ActionType, p.Type, p.Region, a.TimeStamp, a.Action from History p join a in p.Actions where a.TimeStamp >= @StartTime and a.TimeStamp <= @EndTime and p.ClientId = @ClientId and p.ActionType = @ActionType";
if (actionType != "") { sqlString += actionTypeFilter; }

var queryObject = new SqlQuerySpec
{
   QueryText = sqlString,
   Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
   {
      new SqlParameter("@StartTime", startDate),
      new SqlParameter("@EndTime", endDate),
      new SqlParameter("@ClientId", clientId.ToString()),
      new SqlParameter("@ActionType", actionType)
   },
};

var dataListing =  _documentDbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<PnrTransaction>(UriToPnrHistories, queryObject, new FeedOptions() { MaxItemCount = 1 });
```

When I execute this, I'm getting en empty dataset. But when I use the same query, and build it using classic string replace it works just fine.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my parametrized query?

Answer (score 0):

If the code above is the running code, you still add the actiontypeFilter on the parameterized SQL string. Try to remove the if statement on line 2. Seems to me that may be your problem.

It would help if you could post a sample document from the server.

Comment: Post clarification comments under the question, not in answers.

Comment: "You must have 50 reputation to comment"... Working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually see this syntax:

```
SqlParameterCollection parameters = new SqlParameterCollection();
parameters.Add(...);
parameters.Add(...);
```

Try that and see if you get different results. It might be that the list you use to initialize it in your answer needs to be typed differently to work.